# grepl in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, grepl

I'm trying to do a string search and replace across multiple columns in R.  My code:

```
# Get columns of interest
selected_columns <- c(368,370,372,374,376,378,380,382,384,386,388,390,392,394)

#Perform grepl across multiple columns
df[,selected_columns][grepl('apples',df[,selected_columns],ignore.case = TRUE)] <- 'category1'
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Error: undefined columns selected
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep/grepl` works on vectors/matrix and not on `data.frame/list.  According to the`?grep`

> x - a character vector where matches are sought, or an object which can be coerced by as.character to a character vector.

We can loop over the columns (`lapply`) and `replace` the values based on the match

```
df[, selected_columns] <- lapply(df[, selected_columns],
     function(x) replace(x, grepl('apples', x, ignore.case = TRUE), 'category1'))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     mutate_at(selected_columns, ~ replace(., str_detect(., 'apples'), 'category1'))
```

Comment: Thank you,  can you explain what this line of code is doing:      function(x) replace(x, grepl('apples', x, ignore.case = TRUE), 'category1'))

Comment: @DiamondJoe12  `function(x) ` is lambda function or anonymous function which is created on the fly, so, here the `x` refers to each of the column values as a vector on which the `replace` is used to change the values where thee 'apples' are present

Comment: Thanks!  One more question, if I wanted to not just replace "apples" with "category1", but also "apples" AND "oranges", could I do something like:   function(x) replace(x, grepl('apples', 'oranges', x, ignore.case = TRUE), 'category1'))

Comment: I think this works: function(x) replace(x, grepl('apples|oranges', x, ignore.case = TRUE), 'category1'))

Comment: @DiamondJoe12  IN that case use `grepl("apples|oranges", x, ..`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to partially match a cell and replace it, you could use `rapply()` and replace cell contents that have `"apples"` with `"category1`" using `gsub()`:

```
df[selected_columns] <- rapply(df[selected_columns], function(x) gsub("apples", "category1", x), how = "replace")
```

Just keep in mind the difference between `grepl()`/`gsub()` (with and without boundaries in your regex), and `%in%`/`match()` when searching for strings.